# Swap image with media queries without using background image

Tags: css, image, email, media-queries, marketo

I have modified a Marketo responsive email template and need to swap out the header image when the media query hits its breakpoint. However many versions of outlook **do not support background images** (thank you Micro$uk) so is there a way to write the CSS to swap out an image in with src and not background-image? Here is a screen shot from litmus.com you can see the image doesn't appear in many versions of Outlook.

```
<img src="image1"/> to  <img src="image2"/>
```

[image: Litmus Screens]

Comment: You could consider hiding the main header and show a smaller header with a different image. duplicate content yes, but in an email, not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

javascript probably wont work in a lot of email clients. i use the below code for my HTML email templates.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" border="0">
  <span id="mobile">
    <img id="mainimg" class="headimg" src="#" alt="...">
  </span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
span[id=mobile] {
    display:block;
    background-image: url(#) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: top center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: # !important;
}
img[id=mainimg] {
    display: none !important;
}   
}
```

just replace the "#" w/ your links and/or height of the mobile img and you can set that breakpoint to whatever you need it to be. i get really good results and pass all of the litmus test w/ exception of lotus notes.

hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML...

```
<div style="src:www.google.com"></div>
```

And try this in javascript... (I haven't tested it)

```
Element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='www.google.com';
```

Comment: I mentioned a javascript hack to a co-worker and he was like NOOOOOOOOO because of security.